# UIButton titleLabel resizes on press?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to give a UIButton (that was created with resizableImages) some text depending on the pressed state. The behavior I'm seeing is that the width of the button image changes (gets wider) when I press it. What I want is for the text to change when I press it, but for the button to stay the same width. I've fiddled with a number of UIButton options, and haven't had any luck. Here's what I'm currently doing: (Interestingly, the amount the button changes in width appears to be correlated with the width of the button's frame (larger -> more change):

```
UIImage *normalButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonSlice.png"];
UIImage *pressedButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressedSlice.png"];
normalButton = [normalButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 0, 2)];
pressedButton = [pressedButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 0, 2)];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
[myButton setImage:normalButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:pressedButton forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];

[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Highlighted" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setTitle:@"Default" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

//No effect?
myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(ceil(controllerFrame.size.width/2 - 100), 80, 200, 50);
```

Comment: I would say you're fighting against auto-layout (I saw similar behavior, and someone answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264731/why-does-uibutton-resize-when-i-access-titlelabel-property), but I'm not sure that existed when you asked this question.