# Why does UIButton resize when I access titleLabel property?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to adjust the size of a button to (it's intrinsic size + a little bit more) in order to draw a custom background. However, every time I access self.titleLabel within the button, the size and position resnaps to that of the storyboard. I don't have to do anything with the label to reproduce this, just retrieve it from the button.

I've put logging code all over my button and view controller in order to find where this is happening. It's not coming from a relaying-out of subviews or any other notification I see to get within the view controller. The line before accessing titleLabel, the position and size are correct. The line after, it has snapped back to the storyboard position. Commenting out the access prevents the size/position snapping. Can someone tell me where or why this is happening?

I have no constraints set (that I can tell), but am I fighting against auto-layout here? Should I be doing this a different way like composing controls or something?

Something similar (or the same?) has been asked before at [UIButton modifying titlelabel seems to change its frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989162/uibutton-modifying-titlelabel-seems-to-change-its-frame) and [UIButton titleLabel resizes on press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873969/uibutton-titlelabel-resizes-on-press), but both were left unanswered or explained away with just "maybe a bug."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project has auto-layout enabled, then YES, you're fighting auto-layout.  You have two choices, either subclass UIButton so that you can override the intrinsic size calculation, or modify the constraints so that the intrinsic size is not used in any constraint.  If you do the latter, then you probably want to create an IBOutlet to the constraint for the width, so that you can adjust the `constant` property as needed.

Comment: Adding the IBOutlet for the constraint was a huge help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug, it's a consequence of auto layout. When using auto layout, you shouldn't set any frames. Instead, you should change the size or position by modifying the constraints. What's happening, is that whenever the view needs to be redrawn, the frame reverts to the frame that's defined by the constraints.